# How to insert some values in a SQL server table without select statement (e.g from my own created varibales)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I couldn't find any way to insert some new values for some columns in a table in SQL Server without a select statement.

For example I might have some values like *@var1* and *@var2* and I want to insert them in a new row in the table on the columns *COL4* and *COL5* and leave the other columns of the new row Null.

The following code is absolutely wrong but I wish I could write something like this:

```
Insert into myTable
-- add a new row under the lowest row of the table
Values 
   COL4=@var1
   COL5=@var2
-- and leave the other columns empty
```

Comment: Why not use a select statement `SELECT @var1,@var2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use SELECT clause or VALUES clause

```sql
Insert into myTable(Col4,Col5)
SELECT @var1,@var2

Insert into myTable(Col4,Col5)
VALUES(@var1,@var2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use below query to insert data into myTable in selected columns through variables -

```
Insert into myTable
(COL4, COL5)
Values
(@var1, @var2)
```